# MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: ajax

```
@Path("webadd21")
@POST
@BeanParam
@Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)       //接收的
public String doAdd21(Contact contact){

    System.out.println(222);
    System.out.println(contact.getId());
    System.out.println(contact.getName());
}
```

my page request use ajax post a form ,like this:

```
    var dd = $("#testForm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        data : JSON.stringify(dd),
        url : "/arq/rest/booking/webadd21",
        //contentType:"application/json", 
        dataType : "json", 
        success : function(data) {
            //alert(data);
        }
    })
```

but i always get the error 415,how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` works only with `@FormParam` annotated parameters and cannot map to entities:

> the media type "application/x- 
>   www-form-urlencoded" defines parameters in terms of strings and there is no content-type associated with each parameter, thus the general message body readers/writers cannot, like those for JAXB, be utilized in such cases.

Since you are sending json data with ajax, the easier solution is to declare your service as consuming json:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

[This thread](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Jersey-Client-How-can-I-POST-an-object-I-m-getting-an-HTTP-415-error-td2324279.html#a2335344) also suggests using `MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` instead, which seem to work with entities.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include this:

`headers: {Accept: "application/json"},`

on ajax attributes